# How to echo a Page (view) to Ajax Function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am using Codeigniter with Zurb Foundation framewrk. i am tryin to load data in reveal box(fancy popup) using AJAX.. The trick is, i am not loading just the inner html content, but the HTML itself..I mean, i want the function in controller to return the php file to ajax calling function whose contents will be displayed in popup.. My code is

Ajax function call

```
function ajaxfunct() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "welcome/test",
                data: { name: "Jigar", location: "jain" }
            }).done(function( html ) {
                $("#tagUser").append(html);


            });
        }
```

My Controller Code is

```
public function test() {
    $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $data['location'] = $_POST['location'];
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
    echo 'WHAT SHUD I ECHO HERE ?'
}
```

I know the last 2 lines of my Controller code is wrong..I just dont know how to fetch a php file from views folder, process it and pass it to ajax as a pre-processed html(string).

I am not looking for entire code..just  a reference to some function or online tutorials will be great..
thanx

Comment: Check your developer console (I.E. FireBug, Chrome Inspector) to see what you get back from the request, Do a debug on HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already do fetch a PHP file from your views folder in your Controller.

The line

```
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

Loads the /application/views/index.php file and processes it with data from the $data array.

So for Your AJAX call you could make a different view file than index.php like test.php that contain the proper HTML for the AJAX and call it with the line

```
$this->load->view('test', $data);
```

And skip the ECHO part...

Comment: but that would load an entire test.php file in browser..i want to load it only in pop-up box without reloading the current page

Comment: @Jigar. No of course you need a controller function for only your AJAX. I thought that was the test() method?

Comment: @Jigar If you call 'welcome/test' from your AJAX function then the result will be put in your #tagUser container. If you write yourdomain.com/welcome/test in your browser then the same method will output in the browser, however you hould be writing your AJAX controller/model so that this won't output anything without the proper POST data.

Comment: thanx man..your code is working..u rock :) and i was referring to controller initially..the only mistake i made was i was calling index file when i shud have called test file :) silly of me lol.. thank you anyways :)